# sticky menu make it move slower

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

i got a sticky menu that i made:

```
$(function () {
    var menuOffset = $(".outerbox").offset().top;
    $(".p").append(menuOffset);
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop()+2000;

        if (menuOffset <= scrollPos) {
            $(".outerbox").css({ "top": "2000", "position": "fixed", "margin-top": "30px", "margin-right": "0px", "width": "200px", "height": "300px"});
        }
        else {
            $(".outerbox").removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
})
```

Following code is in jquery and works fine. However, when i scroll, it looks too mechanical, i want it to follow my scroll, but more smooth. kind of when you have a transition on an element. How would i go about that?

Comment: Please add your HTML and provide a fiddle or similar. Look into a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean, smooth scrolling the "content" or the "sticky menu"?

Maybe jQuery "[NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html)" or "[jqueryscript](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Smooth-Mouse-Scrolling-scrollSpeed/)" do what you want

Comment: Thank you. its exactly what i want